# Any quadrotor simulation package in ROS Kinetic?

Tags: gazebo, simulation, hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I've been workiing with **quadrotor simulation in gazebo** and **ROS indigo** utilizing hector_quadrotor package. Now I have changed my ROS to **kinetic** and Ubuntu to **16.04.**

 However, hector_quadrotor can be **no longer** utilized due to various compile erros. The main reason I find out is that gazebo 7 no longer support some old APIs which hector_quadrotor calls. I tried to solve these compilation problems but failed.

Could you please tell me some other simulation package available in ROS kinetic with gazebo? Thanks for your advice.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246085/any-quadrotor-simulation-package-in-ros-kinetic?/) by [SilverBullet](https://answers.ros.org/users/20740/silverbullet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2016-10-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-20**:
I've updated your question title to mention the fact that you're looking for packages under Kinetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd totally recommend [hector_quadrotor](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor), it has **kinetic** support and runs on Gazebo.
It works both inside:

[image: image description]

or outside:

[image: image description]

Good thing is that with the hector stack you can have a wide variety of sensors on board already, and you can even integrate slam with [hector_slam](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam).

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2018-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you looked at [this pkg](https://github.com/angelsantamaria/tum_simulator)? It's an adaption of
the [tum_simulator](http://wiki.ros.org/tum_simulator) for the Ardrones to work with Kinetic.

I have run a few basic operations with this pkg on a machine with Ubuntu 16.04, Kinetic and Gazebo 7.

---

Originally posted by [Sidd](https://answers.ros.org/users/22657/sidd/) with karma: 155 on 2018-05-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2